# artifactory plugins best practices

Tags: artifactory

I want to write some artifactory plugins. What is the best way to do that in my ide having code completion available. furthermore I'm looking for good practices for writing tests for the plugins I'm writing. any recommendations? I couldn't find something useful anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDE support is provided by [gdsl file for IntelliJ IDEA](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/ArtifactoryUserPlugins.gdsl) and [dsld file for Eclipse](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/commit/8efa237b3a84b9f62d4ed16529a8401cf7a4f667) (unfortunately, unofficial).

The only tests you can do now is REST calls that will trigger the plugins (for execution) or the events that trigger the plugins (for event listeners) by http-client in integration tests.

Comment: thanks Baruch! I'm already using the gdsl file. One more question. Is there a way to split up a user plugin in multiple groovy files/classes? This way I can at least some of the logic independently.

Comment: It's just groovy code,  which lives inside Tomcat, so you can do whatever you like, e.g. putting all the logic in classes, packaged as jars and put in `WEB-INF/lib`, or only compiled classes put in `WEB-INF/classes`. Reload won't work for them, thought.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like putting most of the logic into a jar, which can be maintained and tested as good as a plain java module and just use a groovy script in the plugins folder as an entry point to that code is a good pattern to get maintainable testable code. thanks again!